# Помогите установить винду

Tags: linux, windows, установка

Надо установить хоть какую рабочую ОС с интернетом и браузером. Есть 2 флешки: одна пустая, на второй сломанная линукс. Я когда пытался установить дебиан, случайно начал устанавливать на флешку с установщиком, линукс с той флешки стартует, но без графики - только консоль. С винтаря, нет возможности загрузиться. Надо как-то или на лайв дебиан с флешки накатить lynx и wget но почему не устанавливается, даже если в сурс листах пути прописать. Или как-то установить имеющийся сломанный линукс на винчестер. Или как-то по сети установить ОС. В идеале конечный результат это винда на компе, но у меня нету ни диска, ни флешки с виндой.

Погите установить Винду.

p.s. дисковод не работает, к соседям с флешкой нет возможности сходить.

**upd:** на сайте не работает кнопка комментировать и дать ответ на собственный вопрос. По этому буду писать здесь. Dmesg log дать не могу, потому что я с телефона. А науте нету графики что бы зайти в браузер. И стартует он с флешки в лайф режиме. На компе линукса нету.

**upd2:** Сеть есть, но нету wget, нечем скачать дистрибутив.

**upd3:** Нашёл wget, скачал с телефона и скинул на комп. Устанавливаю линукс на комп по нижеприведённой инструкции. С установленного дебиана я уже разберусь. Спасибо всем.

Comment: Сломанный linux? тогда давай dmesg лог или скрин запуска ядра.....

Answer (score 12):

1. загружаем консоль линукс c флешки и проверяем есть ли сеть

   ```
   ping ya.ru
   ```

если сеть есть `(ура!)`:

2. скачиваем дебиан 32x или 64x (по умолчанию в папку `/home/username`)

   ```
   wget https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-cd/debian-10.0.0-i386-netinst.iso
   ```

   или

   ```
   wget https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso
   ```
3. смотрим какие жесткие диски (и флешки) есть в системе

   ```
   ls -l /dev/ | grep sd
   ```

   должно вывести что-то типа такого (в моем случае 4 харда + разделы на них)

   ```
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,   0 авг 29 12:47 sda
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,   1 авг 29 12:47 sda1
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,   2 авг 29 12:47 sda2
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,   3 авг 29 12:47 sda3
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,  16 авг 29 12:47 sdb
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,  17 авг 29 12:47 sdb1
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,  32 авг 29 12:47 sdc
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,  33 авг 29 12:47 sdc1
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,  48 авг 29 12:47 sdd
   brw-rw----.  1 root disk        8,  49 авг 29 12:47 sdd1
   ```
4. втыкаем пустую флешку, куда будем писать образ и еще раз выполняем ту же самую команду - смотрим разницу. дожна добавиться еще одна флешка (в моем случае это будет `sde` - пятый диск)
5. флешку можно не монтировать, а сразу писать на нее

   ```
   dd if=/home/username/debian-10.0.0-i386-netinst.iso of=/dev/sde
   ```

   или

   ```
   dd if=/home/username/debian-10.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sde
   ```

   **Важно:** вместо `sde` поставьте свой диск, вместо `username` - соответственно, юзернейм..
6. после того, как `dd` закончит - перезагрузить комп со свежезаписанной флешки и установить `debian` заново (можно будет потом в него виртуал бокс с вендой).